# setAttribute does not work

Tags: javascript, html

I need to add a second attribute to my select options called 'service' but when I check the source only 'value' attribute is set

```
for(var index = 0;  index < list.length; index ++){
        elementToBeAdded.options[index + 1]  = new Option(list[index].description, list[index].id);

        elementToBeAdded.options[index + 1].setAttribute("service",list[index].service);
}
```

**output:**

```
<option value="myValue">
  my text
</option>
```

**expected output:**

```
<option value="myValue" service="myService">
  my text
</option>
```

How can I add an attribute to each option on creation of the option?

Ultimately i need to save an extra value against each option so that I can use it when an option is selected

Comment: Do you get an error in the console?

Comment: *“when I check the source only 'value' attribute is set”* That's to be expected, no? The attribute is only set when the Javascript has run, which does not happen while viewing the source.

Comment: instead of view source, try inspect element in some developer tools and see if it's there

Comment: @user521180 Don't forget to mark an answer as accepted or at least upvote people that helped you ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can make function for this kind of stuffs:

```
function setAttributes(element, attributes) {
  for(var key in attributes) {
    element.setAttribute(key, attributes[key]);
  }
}
```

And use this function like this:

```
setAttributes(option, {"value": "myValue", "service": "myService"});
```

Answer (score 0):

The **'view source'** feature's responsability in most browsers is to show the source as initially read by the browser. Therefore, further changes made to the document through client-side code will not be reflected in the source's viewer. However, you can use your browser's DOM inspector (most browsers have one) to analyse and view an up to date version of the document.

If your goal is to ensure that the attribute was correctly set on the element, you could simply try to retrieve it's value using `yourOption.getAttribute('service')`.